# Use new Gateway as modem and another gateway as a router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, gateway

We recently got TWC internet came with the Ubee ddw365 gateway. For some reason wireless and hardwired the gateway disconnects for a few seconds almost every other minute. At a buddies house I was able to put this same gateway into bridge mode and connect it to a netgear router and just use it as a modem.
My question then is, is there a way I can use a DSL/Broadband Gateway as a router for the same effect or do I have to go buy a true router. I have a 2wire gateway and a netgear 7550 gateway both from AT&T lying around I would like to try and use, but I fear since they both route from the DSL input to their LAN ports I wont be able to use them as routers with the Ubee Cable Gateway acting as modem. Any tips and input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In general, ISP Gateway devices (modem+router all in ones) are not configured to allow the use of an external internet connection. However, if your device has a WAN port, it's possible you can use it without engaging its internal modem component. If your device doesn't have a wan port, in some cases, modified,unofficial firmware can sometimes convert one of the ports to a WAN port (this was the case for many speedtouch DSL gateways).

While possible, all of those options are usually a bad idea. ISPs choose devices for cost and compatibility with their own network - they do not have an interest in maximizing the value in terms of features or support for nonstandard setups. In fact, their interest is to keep the router and wifi portions of the gateway as basic as possible to avoid complicated technical support scenarios. They usually lack a WAN port altogether and are usually a few generations behind in terms of WiFi speeds and chips.

With the low cost of a dedicated router, it's usually advisable to sell your gateway device to another potential customer and purchase a dedicated router.

Comment: any idea then why the gateway would be disconnecting and reconnecting every few seconds? this happens for both wired connections and wireless connections disconnects for a few seconds but it happens almost twice per minute, which is the reason I was trying to circumvent the new gateway in the first place

Comment: I'd yell at your ISP til they fix it & not pay for the service until they do [or rather, get a refund, otherwise they'll just cut you off for not paying]. I had 6 months of free internet til Virgin UK got mine figured out.